# How Do I access the information in my database?

Tags: python, mysql, database, datatables

I am learning how to use databases and I am kind of lost. So far I have created a database through Mysql and I have also created my tables. I have two tables thus far and I plan to take the columns and apply them to lists. I plan to have a separate list variable for every column. For now I am attempting to just print out a column but I just get the error

```
 File "C:/Users/alexa/PycharmProjects/TradeTrakz/Program.py", line 120, in <module>
    myCurs = dbLT.execute("SELECT buy_date FROM longTermTable")
AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'execute'
```

Any help to understand the query features of MySQL will really help! Also when I set a variable like listBuyDate to what tried to pull from the database, will that variable be a list, a string? Also, is there a better way to initiate a TEXT data type? Thanks!

```
import mysql.connector

# creating DataBase for Long Term Tab

dbLT = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    user = "root",
    passwd = "password",
    database = "longTerm"
)

# creating a cursor for database
myCurs = dbLT.cursor()

# making database
# myCurs.execute("CREATE DATABASE longTerm")

# Creating a table

myCurs.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS longTermTable (buy_date VARCHAR(20), \
    stock_name VARCHAR(10), \
    entry_price DECIMAL(10, 2), \
    VOLUME INT(255), \
    sell_date VARCHAR(20), \
    exit_price DECIMAL(10, 2), \
    userId INT(255), \
    account_change DECIMAL(10,2), \
    notes TEXT(90000), \
    divs VARCHAR(20))")

myCurs.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS accountBalanceLT (accountChange DECIMAL(10, 2),\
    dividends VARCHAR(10), \
    withdraw VARCHAR (10)) ")


# myCurs = dbLT.cursor()

myCurs = dbLT.execute("SELECT buy_date FROM longTermTable")
listBuyDate = myCurs.fetchall()

for row in listBuyDate:
    print(row)
```

Comment: dates should be of a `date` type. "all the query feature" is a little to broad and not really a question. A tutorial would suite you better. Start with [the reference guide](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/). `TEXT` types don't need a length.

Comment: Also the error message is pretty clear. You are trying to call the `.execute()` method of a `MySQLConnection` object, which it doesn't have.

Comment: I would start with any basic introductory book or tutorial on sql. Incidentally, note that the number in parentheses following an int declaration is almost meaningless (which is probably just as well, as a 255 magnitude int is probably larger than the number of atoms in the known universe.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this by replacing code:

```
myCurs.execute("SELECT buy_date FROM longTermTable")
listBuyDate = myCurs.fetchall()
```